# bootstrap 3 datetimepicker jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker

i'm using Datetimepicker from https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ for my project.

[image]

what i want to achieve is that the end should not be able to pick time earlier than the start.

```
$('#timePickerStart').datetimepicker({
    format : 'LT'
});
$('#timePickerEnd').datetimepicker({
    format : 'LT'
});
```

the datetimepicker has a function like that for date, but i don't know how to implement it in time.

thanks.

Comment: I did. it uses function minDate and maxDate. and i tried using useCurrent: false but it has a bug, it only works the first time, when i change start time again after inputting the end time, it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: as you don't have any other requirement other then only to make sure the end time not before start time then hassle free solution is, use jQuery validation plugin or bootstrap validation plugin, just put the validation on the time fields and let them do the leg work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable certain time intervals with the `disabledTimeIntervals` property and function. It takes two `moment` objects in an array. The other way is disabling certain hours with the `disabledHours` property and `disabledHours()` function.

What you could do is this: when the user changes one of the pickers, run a callback. In this callback, you can use the `date()` function, to get the current moment, then set it for the other picker as an upper/lower bound with `disabledTimeIntervals`.